# running classic asp page under mvc3 iframe shows compiler error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic, iis-6

we have a big classic asp site and now we have to call this from mvc3 using iframe.
So when we deploy the mvc3 project on iis6 we get compiler error on classic asp page as:

**Compilation Error** 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message**: JS1004: Expected ';'

**Source Error**:

Line 1:  <% Option Explicit 
Line 2:  Session("LoggedOn") = True
Line 3:  %>

Answer (score 0):

Your site has JScript specified as its default language.  Hence in the absence of the header:

```
 <%@ Language="VBScript" %>
```

Code in <% %> will be assumed to be in JScript.  Either change the default language (IIS Mananger | Site Properties | Home Directory | Application Configuration | Options) or add this header to the required pages.

Comment: We follow your first suggestion but still have the problem, by the way when we deploy it on iis 7 it works fine. This problem is occur on both iis 5.1 and 6. And with your second suggestion of adding this header on each file gives following problem

Comment: **Parser Error **
**Parser Error Message:** Cannot use 'JScript' because another language has been specified earlier in this page (or was implied from a CodeFile attribute).

**Source Error: **


'Line 22: 
Line 23: 
Line 24: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JScript" RUNAT="Server" SRC="md5.js"></SCRIPT>
Line 25: <!-- #include file="../common/List/1/clsListData.asp" -->
Line 26: <!-- #include file="../common/Detail/1/clsDetailData.asp" -->'

Comment: and we can't even remove this line.